# A question about uses of induction in particular problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, induction

Suppose we color a table $2n\times 2n$ with four colors such that, each sub-square $2\times 2$ has $4$ different colors. my question is, could we conclude that top left corner, and top right corner , and down right corner
and  down left corner cells have four different colors?

I think the answer is yes and I try to use induction. At the first I give the same colors to cells top left and top right. But at this step I get stuck that how I can find a contradiction.

Comment: I'm confused by the difference between a square and a cell. Is a cell a $2 \times 2$ big square made up of $4$ smaller squares? And is $(1,1)$ the single square on the top left corner of the table?

Comment: @Accelerator I edit my question.

Comment: Okay. And just to make sure, when you say top left corner, top right corner, and so on, you mean they are single squares, right?

Comment: Wouldn't the answer be false? You can just construct a $4 \times 4$ table with the colors red, blue, yellow, and green, where each corner is the same color (e.g. red) and their three adjacent squares are different colors (e.g. blue, yellow, and green)